# get sum of values from mongodb database

Tags: mongodb

this is my document in the sensor collection

```
sensorId:1
sensorType:1
BuildingId:1
CalcItems:
    0: Object
        Ts:2019-08-30T18:30:00.000+00:00
        Value:1
    1:Object
        Ts:2019-08-31T19:00:00.000+00:00
        Value:2
```

i need to get sum of all value attributes with respect to same Ts date value

output like this

```
sensorType:1
BuildingId:1
CalcItems:
    0: Object
        Ts:2019-08-31T18:30:00.000+00:00
        Value:23
    1:Object
        Ts:2019-08-31T19:00:00.000+00:00
        Value:43
```

give me any suggestions

Comment: Is that needs to be grouped by `sensorType`, `BuildingId` & ts also? Seems like same sensor & building has different objects + value even on same day as they're separated by time !!

Comment: @srinivasy, day should be change and i corrected it. there are different sensors in one building and there are many buildings. i need to get sum of the value of one sensor type in one building for each day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

[Sample live demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/dll0xi2yvVo)

```
[
  {
    "$unwind": "$CalcItems"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        "sensorType": "$sensorType",
        "BuildingId": "$BuildingId",
        "Ts": "$CalcItems.Ts"
      },
      "total": {
        "$sum": "$CalcItems.Value"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "sensorType": "$_id.sensorType",
      "BuildingIdVal": "$_id.BuildingId",
      "CalcItems.Ts": "$_id.Ts",
      "CalcItems.Value": "$total"
    }
  }
]
```

Reference

[Mongodb $sum](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/)

[Mongodb $group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/)

[Mongodb $project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/index.html)

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, the calculation worked perfectly. Can you please tell me how to insert the sum of values for each date(Ts) inside the array CalcItems.Because when we project, two documents are made instead of inserting to the same array. Could you please help.

Comment: Can you post the result and sample data here

Comment: here sample data and result   https://docs.google.com/document/d/1XG_ZKsz38KFmhulkoNcgEvdQRwW7d3MaClRiknIuZMg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Try this [Updated demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xNWk4NaQmo0)

Comment: that answer worked brilliantly thank you so much it really helped me a lot Thank You

Comment: in my initial collection, there is sensorId and calcItems only.
there for to use above code i use another collection as mapping.
in mapping collection there ara sensorIds sensorTypes and buildingIds.
and i edited your code and mapping.json file is in this link
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1oI3TLVqfpcQ_Ty5IrOziPatb01CrDW5I?usp=sharing

Comment: I'm sorry. I didn't get what you're trying to convey. Is it working ? If not what changes are required.

Comment: in the sensor collection,  there are only contain sensorId and calcItems array fields. but when calculating sum I need relevant sensorType and buildingId. there for i used mapping collection which contains sensorId, BuildingId, SensorType. In the above link, i attached an example for mapping collection.

Comment: You could do that using using [mergeObjects](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/)

Comment: I found a solution. also, ur answer was more helpful to me. thank you, friend.